# OpenAL: How to add ALUT

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, codeblocks, openal

I am working on a project in Code:Blocks, and have successfully added OpenAL to it.
However, I simply cannot find the so called ALUT to this project. I can't find a .lib file anywhere on the internet, but I have found the source code. I am supposed to compile it with CMAKE, but can't find a guide for that. All the tutorials about CMAKE are way too complex for what I want to do. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716410/where-can-i-get-libraries-for-linking-freealut-openal-under-windows) in the OpenAL feed I saw a recommendation to use [freealut](https://github.com/vancegroup/freealut). If you're going to use ALUT, I'd use that since it's entirely separate library but is seemingly identical to ALUT.